# How to use AHAlertView in iphone project?

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

I have been trying to use AHALertView in my iphone project but it does not work.Even if i run the sample project of AHAlertView, it does not compile and shows as much as 13 errors saying 'undeclared use of identifier' and other warnings as well.
Has anyone faced such problem ? If yes, how do i fix it?

Here is the code:-

```
- (IBAction)addEmail:(id)sender 
{  
      AHAlertView *addFriendAlertView = [[AHAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Add New Contact" message:@"Enter New E-mail"];
      addFriendAlertView.alertViewStyle = AHAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;

      [addFriendAlertView setCancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" block:^{
      NSLog(@"User cancelled the alert instead of entering new address");
 }];

      [addFriendAlertView addButtonWithTitle:@"OK" block:^{
      NSLog(@"User entered the email :- %@",[addFriendAlertView textFieldAtIndex:0].text); 
 }];

      [addFriendAlertView show];
```

Comment: https://github.com/warrenm/AHAlertView is quite detailed, what is undeclared according to the errors?

Comment: Use of undeclared identifier '_presentationStyle','_dissmissalStyle,'_title',etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using the latest XCode version you need to explicitely synthesize this properties like

```
@synthesize presentationStyle = _presentationStyle; etc........
```